# Git Attach Specific Submodule tree

Tags: git, github

I currently have committed [here](https://github.com/chriscct7/jigoshop/tree/dev/vendor), the wordpress-tests submodule. 
Github tells me that the version attached is the latest version of the submodule: 

wordpress-tests @ d983429

However, I wish to attach to an older version, like this
 wordpress-tests @ 460b9c4

The specific Github tree URL to the new version is: 
https://github.com/nb/wordpress-tests/tree/460b9c4ad9db7eea4710f151851060ae1921ea7c

How can I attach the older version to my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to figure it out but basically when you do the gitattributes file, use the tree of the commit.